# C++ How to avoid access of members, of a object that was not yet initialized

Tags: c++, containers

What are good practice options for passing around objects in a program, avoiding accessing non initialized member variables.

I wrote a small example which I think explains the problem very well.

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class container{public:container(){}

    vector<int> LongList;
    bool otherInfo;
};

class Ship
{
public:Ship(){}

    container* pContainer;
};

int main()
{
    //Create contianer on ship1
    Ship ship1;
    ship1.pContainer = new container;
    ship1.pContainer->LongList.push_back(33);
    ship1.pContainer->otherInfo = true;

    Ship ship2;

    //Transfer container from ship1 onto ship2
    ship2.pContainer = ship1.pContainer;
    ship1.pContainer = 0;

    //2000 lines of code further...
    //embedded in 100 if statements....
    bool info = ship1.pContainer->otherInfo;
    //and the program crashes

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good practice is to initialise everything in the objects constructor.

Comment: Ja but this does not help in this case. There is simply no container on ship1 left (In order to stay in the language of my example).

Comment: How does it not? You can initialise the pointer to nullptr.

Comment: Because op is talking about protecting against null pointer dereference, which has nothing to do with an uninitialized member. A uninitialized member have a pretty good chance not to be null in a release compilation. Good practice is to always initialize.

Comment: @Jean Of course it does - if the pointer is not initialised, there is no way of testing if it is null or not.

Comment: See ? We agree. The question is not correctly phrased (states an uninitialized member) or the example does not represent the question (shows a null pointer dereference).

Comment: @newandlost You might want to [edit] your question in order to clarify what exactly you are trying to achieve. This may make it easier to provide better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler cannot determine if you are introducing [*undefined behavior*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42491544/c-how-to-avoid-access-of-members-of-a-object-that-was-not-yet-initialized/42491635#comment72122871_42491635) like shown in your example. So there's no way to determine if the pointer variable was initialized or not, other than initializing it with a *"special value"*.

> What are good practice options for passing around objects in a program, avoiding accessing non initialized member variables.

The best practice is always to initialize the pointer, and check before dereferencing it:

```
class Ship {
public:
    Ship() : pContainer(nullptr) {}             
        // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
    container* pContainer;
};

// ...

if(ship1.pContainer->LongList) {
    ship1.pContainer->LongList.push_back(33);
}
```

---

As for your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42491544/c-how-to-avoid-access-of-members-of-a-object-that-was-not-yet-initialized/42491635#comment72122871_42491635):

> So there are no compiler flags that could warn me?

There are more simple and obvious cases, where the compiler may leave you with a warning:

```
int i;
std::cout << i << std::endl;
```

Spits out

```
main.cpp: In functin 'int main()':
main.cpp:5:18: warning: 'i' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     std::cout << i << std::endl;
                  ^
```

See [Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c05c4bfc251895e7)

Comment: So there are no compiler flags that could warn me?

Comment: @newandlost No, not for that case you presented. There are compler warnings for more obvious cases like `int i; std::cout << i << std::endl;`

Comment: @newandlost As for your edit attempt. No, the `// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^` emphasis comment was put there consciously.

Comment: @newandlost As mentioned a comment for emphasizing what I added to your constructor example.

Comment: Why would you not initialize the pointer to something other than `nullptr`?

Comment: @jaredr What would be the purpose of that?

Comment: May the downvoter please explain thei concern? I didn't DV any of the competing answers, so if it was _in revenge_, the right target isn't me.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Isn't OP trying to _avoid_ nullpt here? Initializing it to nullptr isn't terribly useful in that case.

Comment: @jaredr I can't read that from the OP. It's asking about _uninitialized values_, wich is different from _default `nullptr` initialized values_.

Comment: If you read the comments in the question, OP is asking about avoiding dereferencing null pointers.

Answer (score 2):

One good practice to enforce the checks is to use [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) or [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html).

```
class Ship
{
public:
    Ship() : pContainer(nullptr) {}
    std::optional<container*> Container()
    {
        if(!pContainer)
            return {};
        return pContainer;
    }
private:
    container* pContainer;
};
```

It will force you (or better: provide a firm reminder) to check the result of your getter:

```
std::optional<container*> container = ship1.Container();
container->otherInfo; // will not compile
if(container)
    (*container)->otherInfo; // will compile
```

You would ***always need to check*** the result of operation if you use pointers. What I mean is that with optional the situation is ***more explicit*** and there's less probability that you as the programmer will forget to check the result.

Comment: A bit far fetched, but well ... (I didn't downvote, your answer is legit)

Comment: I like your answer too. The one given by πάντα ῥεῖ is also good.

Comment: I can include optional only via std::experimental::optional. Does the experimental mean it is unsafe?

Comment: @newandlost,  it was newly added to c++17. It should be stable and future compilers will support it.

Comment: I upvoted your answer because I really like it, but accepted the answer of πάντα ῥεῖ because it does not require the "newest" compiler.  But maybe yours will be the standard in some years. I appears very save to me, as you are forcing the user to check with the if statement if the pointer is valid. @πάντα ῥεῖ and AMA, do you think if would be OK if we merge both of your answers for completness?

Comment: @newandlost I've given an upvote as well here. I think it's OK to have both answers staying along separately. They'll gain attention as needed for future research. _@anatolyg_'s answer is another good approach BTW.

Comment: Ok now I fully understand it. But the thing is that 
`std::experimental::optional<container*> opt_cont = ship1.Container();`
`int a = (*opt_cont)->otherInfo;` does also compile... What I mean is that we are not enforced to check the return value of the getter function.... I mean does it then really change something?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are looking for a way to make your code

```
bool info = ship1.pContainer->otherInfo;
```

work even though the `pContainer` may be null.

You can use a sentinel object, which holds some default data:

```
container default_container;
default_container.otherInfo = false; // or whatever the default is
```

Then use a pointer to the sentinel object instead of a null pointer:

```
//Transfer container from ship1 onto ship2
ship2.pContainer = ship1.pContainer;
ship1.pContainer = &default_container; // instead of 0

//2000 lines of code further...
//embedded in 100 if statements....
bool info = ship1.pContainer->otherInfo;
```

If you use this, you should make sure the sentinel object cannot be destroyed (e.g. make it a `static` member, or a singleton).

Also, in the constructor, initialize your pointers so they point to the sentinel object:

```
class Ship
{
public: Ship(): pContainer(&default_container) {}
    ...
};
```

Comment: _"work even though the `pContainer` may be null."_ When should `pContainer` ever be initialized to that `null` value?

Comment: It should never be null. I replaced `nullptr` with a special value, which can be dereferenced.

Comment: Like that one too!

Answer (score 0):

I found an additional solution. It is admittedly not preventing the access of uninitialized objects, but at least the program crashes AND returns an error message, that enables us to correct our mistake. (This solution is particularly for the g++ compiler.)

First of all set the compiler flag `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`. Then instead of naked pointer use `unique_ptr`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class container{

public:container(){}
    int otherInfo = 33;
};

class Ship
{
public:Ship(){}

    std::unique_ptr<container> upContainer;
};

int main()
{
    Ship ship1;

    cout<<ship1.upContainer->otherInfo<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This code will produce an error:

`std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::pointer = container*]: Assertion 'get() != pointer()' failed.`

Hence telling us that we should probably include an `if(ship1.upContainer)` check.

Answer (score -1):

> What are good practice options for passing around objects in a program, avoiding accessing non initialized member variables.

Good practice would be to initialize everything in the constructor.

Debatable better practice is to initialize everything in the constructor *and* provide no way of modifying any members.